# Raphael js unable to create canvas by referencing div

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael

Ive been trying to get this to work for a couple of days now. In the end I just created the canvas manually by entering parameters, but now I actually need to connect it to a div.

The problem is, when trying to create the canvas based on a div, I always get the same error from Raphael JS:

```
TypeError: b is undefined
```

Heres a quick jsFiddle, but you will see the same results in Firebug (although it shows a different library name, it is rapheal causing it)

http://jsfiddle.net/GXXuD/3/

Please help! Its driving me crazy.

Comment: At least in your fiddle, the id of your div is misspelled

Comment: Oh yeah! Sorry about that, Ill update. I think Ive almost found a solution but Ill keep this question up to point out the problem anyway. Ill answer it when Im done

Comment: this is all in your head, see [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXXuD/4/) - the paper is created just fine. only changed the hook for the paper to be consistent, and corrected the flawed CSS property (`background_color` to `background-color`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found of doing this didnt relate to the documentation, I just had to hack it. If anyone else comes across the problem of getting Rapheal js to assign a canvas/paper to a div, this method works fine.

**JS**

```
var new_width = $('#map img').width();
var new_height = $('#map img').height();

$('#map').css({'height':new_height, 'width':new_width});
var paper = new Raphael("canvas", new_width, new_height);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='map'>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
    <img src="path/to/image"/>
</div>
```